# react-native gesture handler module not recognized on ios

Tags: react-native-gesture-handler

Same error that has been asked a gazillion times.  My package.json contains:

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"expo": "^44.0.6",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
```

According to the documentation I don't need to link but since none of the other answers worked I ran:

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
and pod install in ios directory.
```

I also installed with expo:
and added: `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';`
This didn't work so I tried the regular

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
```

After installation, wrap your entry point with `<GestureHandlerRootView>`

```
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <GalioProvider theme={nowTheme}>
              <Block flex>
                <Screens />
              </Block>
            </GalioProvider>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
```

This also didn't work.  Any ideas on what else I can try?